# Positive definiteness and vectorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-characteristic

If matrix $A$ is positive definite, what properties does its vectorization column vector has? Here vectorization means $\operatorname{vec}(A)$, that is to make it into a single column by list first column, then 2nd column, then 3rd.

Comment: Why would you want to study this? It seems you have strictly less structure on these vectors after this transformation.

Comment: what do you mean strictly less structure? I was encounter a engineering problem needs to prove something..hard to explain in simple plain math language.

Comment: By less structure I mean a matrix's form had encoded in it the dimension each vector. The 'vectorization' of A does not have any information about that. In particular, it's indistinguishable from just an ordinary vector in a larger space. Unless I have some context on the kind of properties you might expect $vec(A)$ to have, I really don't know where to start.

Comment: oh...positive definiteness means $A=LL^*$ for some $L$ and A is Hermitian symmetric.

Comment: Ok, so what might an analogue of that be for $vec(A)$? What are you hoping is true?

Comment: Suppose $vec(A)=B*vec(D)$ and B and D both positive definite. B is also Hermitian symmetric. I was hoping A is also positive definite.   I found I maybe can use this property $vec(ABC)=(C^T \otimes A)vec(B)$

Comment: That's a more interesting question. That makes sense where you're coming from now.

Comment: Yeah, this is a more interesting question. My problem here is B has a structure of $B=X \otimes Y$. I was hoping A is positive definite both when B has this structure and without this structure.

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately not known easy interesting exact condition on $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ besides the trivial ones; e.g. diagonal matrices.

There is one in the sense that a symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if all its principal minors are positive. This translates into a nonlinear system of inequalities in the entries of $\operatorname{vec}(A)$, but this is not something which is particularly useful.

If you are just interested in sufficient conditions. You can state one in terms of strict diagonal dominance which states that $A$ is positive definite if the diagonal entries of $A$ are positive and $A1>0$ where $1$ is a vector of ones, and the inequality is component-wise. This directly translates into conditions on some of the entries of $\operatorname{vec}(A) but nothing is gained here.

We may also look at the product $A=BB^T$ for some square matrix $B$, which yields

$$\operatorname{vec}(BB^T)=(B\otimes B)\operatorname{vec}(I),$$

but one can see that $B\otimes B$ may fail to be symmetric and, even if it were, may also fail to be positive definite.

Finally, it is easy to construct a counterexample to the fact that $\operatorname{vec}(A)=B\operatorname{vec}(D)$ with $B,D$ are symmetric and positive definite and such that $A$ is symmetric implies that that $A$ is also positive definite. Note that $B$ needs to have a very specific structure here to guarantee that $A$ is symmetric.

So, let $D=I$ and

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 4 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 8 & -2\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, we have that
$$B\operatorname{vec}(D)=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
-2\\
1
\end{bmatrix},$$

which yields to
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\
-2 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$

which is not positive definite.